# Webbrowser control on Windows 10 (>= 1609) and http/2

Tags: .net

I am wondering if there is any setting to have the **webbrowser control** (Embedded IE 11) use **HTTP/2** on **Windows 10**.

I have set the value for my process within `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` to `11001`. External IE is using http 2.0 but any requests from the webbrowser control always uses http 1.1.

I am making https calls against an internal Windows 2016 server running IIS and I am able to determine the request protocol via the IIS server logs for a test app using the  **webbrowser control**.

Answer (score 3):

I found out by trial and error along that they key is FEATURE_WEBOC_ENABLE_HTTP2. A DWORD value that is named after the process must be created with a value of 1 to enable this feature. This is not documented anywhere and I found the key by luck.